# Exclude extension from an output file in PS?

Tags: powershell

My goal is to display items in the directory `C:\test` in a log file called `log.txt` without displaying the file-extensions of the files found, e.g. `.zip`, `.pdf`, etc.

My script so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\ -name |Out-File C:\test2\log.txt
```

How do I get the `.log` file to NOT display the extensions of the files found in the `C:\test` folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `BaseName` property instead of `Name`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName | Out-File C:\test2\log.txt
```

As there's no built-in `-BaseName` property for `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, you need to get that property using `Select-Object`. Expanding the property allows you to get only the value of chosen property, without the header.

Another way to get `BaseName` value would be to use `.BaseName` like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\).BaseName | Out-File C:\test2\log.txt
```

That form is shorter, but *personally* I prefer the first one due to readability and no need to remember about surrounding braces `()`.

---

### Best practice

If you want to inspect what are the possible properties (and their values) of the object you have, you can also use `Select-Object` for that:

```bsh
# Warning: HUGE OUTPUT POSSIBLE
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\| Select-Object *
# It's usually good to take only one object from the array
$obj = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test\)[0]
$obj | Select-Object *
```